# bootstrap dropdown button doesn't drop down using bootstrap 4

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap-4, drop-down-menu, popper.js

I am creating a flask app with bootstrap. I am trying to use an element that requires jquery + popper, such as a dropdown menu. The button is showing up, but it's not dropping down

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <title>hello world</title>
  </head>

   <div class="dropdown">
   <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Dropdown button
   </button>
   <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
   </div>
   </div>

    <script src="/static/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"</script>
    <script src="/static/node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.min.js" </script>
    <script src="/static/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" </script>
  <body>
</html>
```

For reference, here's what my file tree looks like

[image]

These are the versions of the dependencies that I have installed (installed using yarn)

1. @popperjs/core@2.4.4
2. bootstrap@4.5.2
3. jquery@3.3.1
4. popper.js@1.16.1

There are no error messages showing up in the console

When I just reference the scripts like this I have not had any problems

> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I have seen a *lot* of related questions, but none of the solutions that were suggested have worked so far. Here is the advice that I have seen so far:

1. make sure that the jquery script comes before the bootstrap script (check)
2. remove the popper dependency and use bootstrap.bundle.js or bootstrap.bundle.min.js (I have tried both)
3. make sure you're not including the bootstrap jquery twice (check)
4. Add  `<script>$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();</script>` (did not work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to close script tags in your index.html

```
<script src="/static/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: All three of them end in </script>. Am I missing something else?

Comment: > I want to explain are missing in <script .... Try my code and say result

Comment: this works, but it turned out that I had an additional problem - I was also importing "/static/node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.min.js" but I needed to import "/static/node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"

Comment: `<script src="/static/node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>` ?